# Need help reformatting PowerPoint slide containing latex code

Tags: indentation, algorithms, powerpoint

Consider the following PowerPoint slide:

[image]

This was produced with the help of [IguanaTex](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/) plugin, which allows you to generate pictures from latex snippets, and add them to your PowerPoint slides.

The above is really composed of three images: the one with the INPUT caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mywhite}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\color{mywhite}

\begin{document}

    \textsc{Input:} \hspace{15pt}     $n$ terminal nodes: $V_1,V_2,...,V_n$\\
    \hspace{50pt} and their corresponding weights: $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$

\end{document}
```

The one with the OUTPUT caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mywhite}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\color{mywhite}

\begin{document}

    \textsc{Output:} \hspace{3pt} Optimal extended binary tree\\
    \hspace{51pt} i.e. $T$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^nw_il_i$ is minimal

\end{document}
```

And the one holding the algorithm:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mywhite}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\color{mywhite}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=8.5cm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Huffman's Algorithm}
        \label{CHalgorithm}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \State Initialize minimum heap $Q$ with $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$
            \While {$Q.\text{size()}> 1$}
            \State $w_i\leftarrow Q.\text{extractMin()}$
            \State $w_j\leftarrow Q.\text{extractMin()}$
            \State $w_k\leftarrow w_i+w_j$
            \State Instantiate internal node $v_k$, with weight $w_k$
            \State Set $v_k$ as the father of $v_i$ and $v_j$
            \State $Q.\text{add}(w_k)$
            \EndWhile
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

It's nice to have the ability to make images out of snippets, since this provides to agility of moving blocks (images) of text around freely; capability that would otherwise achieved by creating one snippet with the proper adaptions and refinements in code - and these are skills that I don't have.
But in this case, the formatting in the above picture just look awful to me, and the INPUT and OUTPUT code snippets are very poorly written (the `\hspace{}` "solution" to achieve proper indentation feels wrong and looks ugly).
This is where I need help. Well, actually not just that. I need advice in the following topics:

1. First, and maybe the most easiest: refer to the algorithm's `\caption{}` tag. This tag adds the unwanted "Algorithm 1" text to my caption. Is the `\caption{}` tag customizable? How can I remove this added text and left with just "Huffman's Algorithm"?
2. Is there a better way to control the indentation for the INPUT and OUTPUT snippets?
3. In fact, I'd even prefer to have this format instead:

---

(**The following was created with MS paint**, I took the above picture and move stuff around with the cutting tools)

[image]

---

I'd prefer it will all sit in one snippet of code, instead of patching together several images.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's much extra work to include the "input", "output" and "algorithm" groups all in one (LaTeX) document. Note the use of a two-column `tabularx` environment to hold the "input" and "output" groups. If you don't want a caption for the "algorithm" environment, don't provide a `\caption` statement.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=8.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,amsmath,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
\hrule%
Huffmann's Algorithm \strut
\hrule
\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lY @{}}
\textsc{Input:} &$n$ terminal nodes: $V_1,V_2,\dots,V_n$ and their corresponding weights: $w_1,w_2,\dots, w_n$ \\[0.75\baselineskip]
\textsc{Output:} & Optimal extended binary tree, i.e., $T$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n w_il_i$ is minimal
\end{tabularx}

\begin{algorithm}
%\caption{Huffman's Algorithm}
%\label{CHalgorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \State Initialize minimum heap $Q$ with $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n$
            \While {$Q.\text{size()}> 1$}
            \State $w_i\leftarrow Q.\text{extractMin()}$
            \State $w_j\leftarrow Q.\text{extractMin()}$
            \State $w_k\leftarrow w_i+w_j$
            \State Instantiate internal node $v_k$, with weight $w_k$
            \State Set $v_k$ as the father of $v_i$ and $v_j$
            \State $Q.\text{add}(w_k)$
            \EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tabular` is probably the easiest solution, since it is only as wide as it needs to be.  I set the default spacing between columns to zero, so you have to add spacing using `@{...}` where you want it.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\tabcolsep=0pt
\begin{tabular}{l@{ }l}
\textsc{Input:} & $n$ terminal nodes: $V_1,V_2,...,V_n$ \\
  & and their corresponding weights: $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$ \\[20pt]
\textsc{Output:} & Optimal extended binary tree \\
  & i.e. $T$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^nw_il_i$ is minimal
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: standalone tabular]